# Combining Input and Button into an InputButton component

Tags: c#, blazor

## Example

Let's suppose I have the following bit of code:

```
@code {
    private decimal abc = 0;
    private decimal bcd = 0;
}

<input @bind-value="abc"/>
<button>@abc</button>
<br />

<input @bind-value="bcd"/>
<button>@bcd</button>
<br />
```

If I change the input values, the buttons update:

[image]

## Using InputButton component

Now, let's say I'd like to have an `InputButton` component which can be used to setup one of those `input` and `button` pairs.

In `Shared\InputButton.razor` I have:

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public decimal Val { get; set; }
}

<input @bind="Val" />
<button>@Val</button>
```

Now, if I update the original code to use an `InputButton`:

```
@code {
    private decimal abc = 0;
    private decimal bcd = 0;
}

<input @bind-value="abc"/>
<button>@abc</button>
<br />

<input @bind-value="bcd"/>
<button>@bcd</button>
<br />

<InputButton Val="abc" />
```

while it does render:

[image]

if I change the third `input` (generated by `InputButton`) it does not change `abc`. (As you can see there, I entered `3` into the input field but the first input and button did not change.

However, if I change the first input, the third is affected:

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to have `InputButton` change the variable that is passed to it?

## Live example

Here's a blazorfiddle which sets up the above:

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/i3wx120z

Answer (score 2):

You could use either a state service or a EventCallback , callback is simpler to implement for a parent/child set-up

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<decimal> ParentCallBack { get; set; }

private async Task HandleInputValueChange(KeyboardEventArgs e){
  Decimal.TryParse(e.Key, out decimal @parsedDec);
  await ParentCallBack.InvokeAsync(parsedDec);
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/u1zuy3by)

Comment: Your welcome, please mark as answered if it's worked for you :)

Comment: I was able to use an approach that doesn't involve providing an explicit callback each time. See below.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an approach that works:

```
@code {
    private decimal _value;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<decimal> ValChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public decimal Val 
    {
        get => _value;

        set
        {
            if (_value == value) return;

            _value = value;

            ValChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
}

<input @bind="@Val"/>
<button>@Val</button>
```

Blazor fiddle:

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/uvxvwvvy